Cannot Import Function in Module with Golang workspace
What I need
I can write almost all the functions in the module I created, except the one thing I need most is undefined... I really need to use this function
Directory and files
Directory Hierarchy
workdir
    main.go
    go.mod
    go.work
    userinfo
        userinfo.go
        go.mod

workdir/go.mod
module example.com/workdir

go 1.21.5

workdir/go.work
go 1.21.5

use (
    .
    ./userinfo
)

workdir/userinfo/go.mod
module example.com/userinfo

go 1.21.5

Detailed explanation
The first idea was simple... I was tired of typing username and password into the database over ssh every time, so I wanted to store the username and password in the config, and have it pull them out whenever I needed them.
So I wrote a bunch of functions in the workdir/userinfo directory to encrypt the username and password with the rsa algorithm, set the public and private keys to this and that, etc.
And finally, I put in a function that would always enter my commands exactly as they should be.
func comExec(dbCommand string) (string, error) {

    var result string
    // Load private key for decryption
    privateKey, err := LoadPrivateKey()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Read and decrypt credentials
    user, password, err := ReadCredentials(privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    //execute command with db argument
    cmd := exec.Command("myDatabase", dbCommand, "--address=http://localhost.com/db", "--username", user, "--password", password)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out

    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    result = out.String()
    return result, nil
}

Obviously, while I was creating this module, I could type go run userinfo.go and everything worked perfectly.
So naturally, I created main.go in my workdir, and I put these functions in there.
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "example.com/userinfo"
)

func main() {

    var comm := string
    fmt.Scanf("what do you want : %s", &comm)

    result, err := userinfo.comExec(comm)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error occurs:", err)
        return
    }

    // Print the fourth part of the command output
    outputParts := strings.Split(result, "\n")
    if len(outputParts) >= 4 {
        fmt.Println(outputParts[3])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Insufficient output from command")
    }
}

and then, undefined: userinfo.comExec  compiler(UndeclaredImportedName) comes to me.
Added
It's only occurs to comExec function.
I use vscode, obviously it has automatic completion, and in my userinfo.go, there are bunch of functions, such as decrypt, encrypt, generateRSAkeys etc. vscode can complete those functions when I stopped at userinfo. but no comExec only.
Added 2
https://youtu.be/RGrEUGCrT4g
I recorded myself, as you can see, when I save the file, imported module disappeared, because there are no function is from the module, actually it exactly there!

Obviously you can import other packages in Go. You did not post essential parts of your configuration, like your go.mod file. See for example “Organizing a Go module.”

Everything here is wrong. Never use filename arguments to go run. Dont use go run at all, get used to go build. You cannot import unexported stuff. Take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals. Don't use several modules for things that belong into one module.

@Volker That's really good info that I should use build instead of run, thanks. But if I want to use build, I shouldn't get an error. How can I use build when I can't save because of an error.

Again: You must export your function and you should not use multiple modules.

@Volker Thanks so much for the advice on export. If you would have written Capitalize Your First Letter Of Function Name after export your function, before you posted the same comment twice, I wouldn't have had to spend 20 minutes asking GPT what the hell export is. But thanks anyway.

These are absolute language fundamentals that are covered in the Tour of Go which you are expected to work through. No need to google, no need for AI nonsensen, just consult the official documentation on go.dev.

You can try commands like go work sync , go mod tidy and go get "example.com/userinfo"   .                                                        Also better to make comExec  to ComExec this can help in making the function exported.          You can refer official golang document about working with multiple modules  https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces
